# What DNA does a self-fertile plant's seedling have?

Tags: genetics, botany, seeds

Some plants are said to be `self-fertile`. An example is `Prunus tomentosa`.

Assuming that no cross-pollination happened with other plants, if a self-fertile plant such as `prunus tomentosa` produces a seedling, what DNA will the seedling have? Is the seedling's DNA an exact copy of the parent plant's DNA, or do the genes get rearranged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Selfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfing) (aka self-fertilizing) differs from [cloning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning#Natural_cloning). When selfing occurs, the offspring is not an exact copy of the parent. When cloning occurs, the offspring is an exact copy (except for a few mutations) of the parent.

Selfing implies that an individual will produce two [gametes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamete) (typically a spermatozoid and an ovule but that might be a bit more complicated) and these two gametes are fusing to give the [zygote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygote) (egg or offspring if you prefer).

As a consequence, when selfing, [meiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis) is occurring (and therefore [segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendelian_inheritance#Law_of_Segregation_of_genes_.28the_.22First_Law.22.29) and [recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_recombination)) so that the offspring is not an exact clone of the parent but rather some kind of a rearrangement of the parent genome (with a few mutations of course).

Comment: This question might be of interest: [Peach pits with multiple seeds: Do the seeds have the same DNA?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/70233/peach-pits-with-multiple-seeds-do-the-seeds-have-the-same-dna)

Comment: This question might be of interest: [Peach pits with two seeds: Are the seeds identical twins?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/70233/peach-pits-with-two-seeds-are-the-seeds-identical-twins)